# Analytic criteria for the support of the Plancherel measure for SL(2,Qp), spherical functions

Tags: unitary-representations

Is there an analytic criteria to determine the support of the Plancherel measure for SL(2,Qp). At least for unitary spherical representations

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you get all spherical tempered representations. These correspond to the unitary reps of the Levi subgroup modulo the Weyl group action.

The only non-tempered unitary reps are among the spherical. So the non-spherical unitary representations are all tempered and appear in the right regular representation.

Temperedness is equivalent to having almost square-integrable matrix coefficients.

Comment: Thks a lot, I understand this now. What I can not get is somehow a divergence criteria in terms of the computation of  traces that will prove directly- maybe it doesn't exist, but I have the feeling that taking traces of characteristic functions of small support, would give a divergence. I can see a way to compute this, but seems very long

Comment: Characteristic functions are not smooth. Growth considerations are pretty analytic to me. For any thing else, there are not that many analytic differences between the characters. It's like $x \mapsto e^{sx}$ for $s$ varying and $s$ being imaginary means temperedness.